# Wrap each element in variadic macro with an expression

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

### Problem:

I'm looking to write a variadic macro

```
#define WRAP(token, ...)
```

which, when called with a token and N arguments

```
WRAP(decltype, a, b, c)
```

will expand into a comma-separated list of the arguments wrapped in the token

```
decltype(a), decltype(b), decltype(c)
```

This would allow me to write something like the following:

```
#define MACRO(...) \
    Class< WRAP(decltype, __VA_ARGS__) >::Function();
```

If I call it as follows:

```
MACRO(a, b, c)
```

it would result in:

```
Class<decltype(a), decltype(b), decltype(c)>::Function(0;
```

I have no idea how to achieve this. Is it possible? Perhaps with [`BOOST_PP`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) or some such?

### Motivation:

I have a macro for logging:

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) \
    logger::instance().push(__FUNCTION__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);
```

I have a variadic class template which is able to verify the arguments match the provided format string

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct Format
{
    template<std::size_t N>
    static constexpr bool check(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n);
};
```

If I define a macro with a fixed number of arguments I can call my format checking function:

```
#define LOG(fmt, a) \
    static_assert(Format<decltype(a1)>::check(fmt, 0), ""); \
    logger::instance().push(__FUNCTION__, fmt, a);
```

However, if I use a variadic macro, this won't work for more than 1 argument:

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) \
    static_assert(Format<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>::check(fmt, 0), ""); \
    logger::instance().push(__FUNCTION__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);
```

That's because `decltype(__VA_ARGS__)` is obviously invalid syntax.

to fix it, I need to expand `__VA_ARGS__` into `decltype(a1), decltype(a2), decltype(a3)`

### Variadic function template?

I have tried to achieve this using a `constexpr` variadic function template, but I am unable to pass `fmt` to a `static_assert` as it is no longer a string literal at this point:

```
template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
constexpr void check(const char (&fmt)[N], const Ts&...)
{
    static_assert(Format<Ts...>::check(fmt, 0), "");
}
```

Trying to call this check function

```
check("%s", "hello world");
```

fails to compile:

```
main.cpp:216:46:   in constexpr expansion of ‘Format<T, Ts ...>::check<7ul>((* & fmt), 0ul)’
main.cpp:216:5: error: ‘fmt’ is not a constant expression
```

Comment: Why not use a variadic function template instead? It preserves type information and you can use the deduced parameter pack to decide the type of `Format<>`.

Comment: Why is a function with variadic template argument not enough here? template <class... Types> void log(Types... args) { return Class<Types...>(args...); }

Comment: Further, if I pass `fmt` to a function, such that it's type is `const char (&fmt)[N]`, I cannot use that in a `static_assert`: The following fails to compile: `template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
constexpr void check(const char (&fmt)[N], const Ts&...)
{
    static_assert(Format<Ts...>::check(fmt, 0), "");
}` with error `‘fmt’ is not a constant expression`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple with Boost.PP:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define COMMA_SEP(r, token, i, e) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i) token(e)
#define WRAP(token, ...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(COMMA_SEP, token, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```

**Edit**: The above won't work if `__VA_ARGS__` is empty, to solve that, please refer to [this solution](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/), but note that the solution won't work for MSVC because their preprocessor is non-standard-conformant, if you want to support MSVC, just use `BOOST_PP_IS_EMPTY` in place of `ISEMPTY`.

Comment: thanks - I knew it would be easy - but damn that documentation is hard to figure out!

Comment: Hmm, do you know how to make the `WRAP` sequence evaluate to nothing if `__VA_ARGS__` is empty? That is: `WRAP(decltype, 1)` evaluates to `decltype(1)`, and `WRAP(decltype)` evaluates to nothing. As it is, it won't work for the no-argument case

Comment: Ah thanks - I had just posted another question asking this - will check out the link you posted